# Criticality in liquid thorium fluoride reactors

Tags: nuclear-engineering

I have been reading up a bit about LFTRs over the past few days. Regarding safety, the argument of the people is that at the bottom of the reactor, there will be a salt plug that will be cooled by air or some other mechanism. If the reactor fails, the cooling will stop and the reactor's contents will pour out into the drainage tank.

Now, in the drainage tank, one must not achieve criticality as then it would overheat. My question is that if the molten salt must not achieve criticality in the drainage tank, how does it achieve criticality in the reaction core vessel. Is it due to the presence of some moderator such as graphite? Or is it due to the geometry of the core?

If it is due to a moderator such as graphite, one would necessarily need the graphite for moderation. However, the graphite does deteriorate in terms of mechanical properties over time. Please point out any inaccuracies in the above thought.

Thanks!

(For a schematic of the reactor, please have a look at this link : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molten_salt_reactor#/media/File:Molten_Salt_Reactor.svg)

Comment: Criticality in a reactor is very sensitive to both geometric neutron loss and moderation (if in the design). Since the dump tank would not have a moderator, and would be designed to not be a critical-possible geometry, the answer is 'both'.